# Python: How to use a dictionary to call methods (values in dictionary) to run based on user input (key in dictionary) in a different function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lookup-tables

What I have so far:

```
def run_A():
   # code...

def run_B():
   # code...

def run_C():
   # code...

inputDict = {'a': run_A, 'b': run_B, 'c': run_C, 'q': False}  # q for quit program
def userChoice(self):
    y = True
    while y:
       choice = input("a. run A\nb. run B\nc. run C\nq. Quit").lower()
       self.inputDict[choice]
```

My issue here is that the program allows the user to input their choice, but the function will be called based on dictionary (won't run) and program will only keep asking user for their choice.

Comment: If the functions are part of a class, please write the entire code here.

Comment: From your question it looks like you have two problems 1: the dictionary call doesn't run the function because it retrieves the function name. This can be solved with the answers below about 'eval()'. But your second problem about "program will only keep asking user for their choice", if you want to fix that we need to know what you want. Do you want the program to only ask once (remove the `while`)? Do you want it to ask once every time the user gives an input?

Answer (score 7):

`self.inputDict[choice]` will just get function from dict, and won't call it, so maybe you need replace `self.inputDict[choice]` with `self.inputDict[choice]()`

Comment: I figured it out: it should be ```self.inputDict[choice](self)```

Answer (score 3):

```
def run_A():
    print("A")
   # code...

def run_B():
    print("B")
   # code...

def run_C():
    print("C")
   # code...

inputDict = {'a': run_A, 'b': run_B, 'c': run_C, 'q': False}  # q for quit program
def userChoice(self):
    y = True
    while y:
       choice = input("a. run A\nb. run B\nc. run C\nq. Quit").lower()
       if choice =="q":
           y = False
       else:
           self.inputDict[choice]()
```